# How to use Calabash x-platform with Amazon Device Farm

Tags: amazon-web-services, calabash, aws-device-farm

I am planning to use x-platform frameworks with Amazon device farm but the x-platform folder hierarchy is different than what Amazon is accepting. Is there any way to solve this?

There is a [thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=775493&tstart=0) in amazon forum but it was solved by not using x-platform.

[image]

what x-platform is:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work for the AWS Device Farm team.

1. Device Farm accepts a zip file which is the zipped features folder.
   So if all of you test code were under features folder you would zip the features folder. 
   After unzipping the features folder should not have another features folder inside it.
2. Also if you have customer code in env.rb or 01_launch.rb files this can cause the tests to be not parsed on Device farm. It does a dry run of your test package before it can start running the tests.
3. If you are reading ENV for platform that will be another reason why it will not get parsed on device farm.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks seems like it needs some development for amazon but xamarin is given support for x-platform.